# Error is cannot find Symbol in BufferedReader and InputstreamReader

Tags: java

```
class ArithmeticExceptionDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        InputStreamReader ir=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=  new BufferedReader(ir);
        System.out.println("Enter First Number=");
        int a=Integer.ParseInt(br.read());;
        System.out.println("Enter Second Number="+a);
        int b=Integer.ParseInt(br.read());``
        //Exception Handeling
        try {
            int c=a/b;
            System.out.println("Result is ="+c);
        } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

THE ERROR IS:

C:\Users\Micky\Documents\practice>javac ArithmeticExceptionDemo.jav

```
ArithmeticExceptionDemo.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
            InputStreamReader ir=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            ^
      symbol:   class InputStreamReader
      location: class ArithmeticExceptionDemo
ArithmeticExceptionDemo.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
            InputStreamReader ir=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                                     ^
      symbol:   class InputStreamReader
      location: class ArithmeticExceptionDemo
ArithmeticExceptionDemo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            BufferedReader br=  new BufferedReader(ir);
            ^
      symbol:   class BufferedReader
      location: class ArithmeticExceptionDemo
ArithmeticExceptionDemo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            BufferedReader br=  new BufferedReader(ir);

ArithmeticExceptionDemo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            BufferedReader br=  new BufferedReader(ir);
            ^
      symbol:   class BufferedReader
      location: class ArithmeticExceptionDemo
ArithmeticExceptionDemo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            BufferedReader br=  new BufferedReader(ir);
ArithmeticExceptionDemo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            BufferedReader br=  new BufferedReader(ir);
            ^
      symbol:   class BufferedReader
      location: class ArithmeticExceptionDemo
ArithmeticExceptionDemo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            BufferedReader br=  new BufferedReader(ir);

                                    ^
      symbol:   class BufferedReader
```

Any help that i can fix my issues.Thank You

Comment: `import java.io`?

Comment: Looks like you didn't import the required classes. Try `import java.io.*;` (or individual `import` statements for each class) at the top of the file (after any `package` statement).

Comment: See [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your corrected code is as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ArithmeticExceptionDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStreamReader ir=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=  new BufferedReader(ir);
        System.out.println("Enter First Number: ");
        int a = 0;
        try {
            a = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("You entered " + a);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter Second Number: ");
        int b = 0;
        try {
            b = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("You entered " + b);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Exception Handling
        try {
            double c = (double) a / (double) b;
            System.out.println("Result is: " + c);
        } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Your original code had many, many errors. Here are just a few examples:

1. "int b=Integer.ParseInt(br.read());``" What is with the "``" at the end?
2. No import statements were included with your code.
3. You were missing a } at the end of your program (may have been a copy/paste error).
4. You used br.read() instead of br.readLine() (to solve the problem of newline characters).
5. parseInt() was incorrectly capitalized (as ParseInt()).

The errors about the symbols, however, were caused by the missing import statements. Next time, consider using an IDE that provides errors when imports are missing (such as Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

To use BufferedReader, your header file must include

> > import java.io.*;